# Is it an issue to run both apache and node.js

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I'm a rookie in server side , so please do excuse me if my question is foolish.Basically I'm running `apache` and `node.js` in server .Thus is it a performance killer ? Should i remove the `apache` and if I would then can i access the server through ftp clients like `filezilla` or should I install `nginx` on server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx would be easier to configure also it will be better than apache when it comes to serving static content like images and CSS files and so on.

If you would like to access the project through FTP you need to install FTP service like `vsftpd` on your server which will makes you able to access your files through filezilla as this has nothing to do with the webserver.

Comment: Sir , great thanks for your enlightenment . You've cleared all my doubts.